# CodeBlocks IDE Open CV MingW Windows 7

Tags: opencv, gcc, g++, mingw, codeblocks

I have installed Codeblocks with MingW, followed the instructions given [HERE](http://kevinhughes.ca/tutorials/opencv-install-on-windows-with-codeblocks-and-mingw/)

I downloaded CodeBlocks with MingW. Followed the instructions in the above link, and wrote the following program

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Testing";
    Mat image;// new blank image
    image = cv::imread("test.png", 0);// read the file
    namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// create a window for display.
    imshow( "Display window", image );// show our image inside it.
    waitKey(0);// wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

Default compiler options set to GCC Compiler.
When I clicked Build and Run button on the IDE, it showed an "Entry Point Not Found" error message that says "The Procedure entry point__gxx_personality_v0 could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll"

I dont understand what is happening. I have been trying to run this small code with various IDEs. I could not understand what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am the creator of the tutorial you followed! I've updated it to fix this issue - Namely the best way to use OpenCV with MinGW on Windows currently is to build your own binaries using cmake.

Best,
Kevin